# Login with Facebook in 2023. How to solve restrictions

Tags: facebook

I have the website and the mobile app. There is the integration with facebook to allow users "Login with Facebook". It works.
But in 2023 (recently) i wanted to make another similar app. Website + mobile apps. I had to create new facebook application. But i found it is not so easy as before.
My integration is only for login. It reads users name, email and icon (image). Email is not so important but even if i skip reading email there is still a problem.

So, Facebook doesn't allow me to do this process till i do "Verification of the business". It redirects to "Meta for business" and here i have to add new "business" and confirm it. I have to provide some documents to proof i am business owner etc.
But i have no any business!!!
I just want to allow my users to click the button "Login with facebook" and to be authorized on my website and mobile apps.

How to solve this? Is it possible at all to make new app for such purposes? Or "Login with facebook" is not any option anymore? Must i to drop this integration?

**Update**.
Facebook documentation really says public_profile can be read only with business verified app.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/public_profile
But i can not get it. Does it mean "Login with facebook" is not not allowed for non-business websites? Like hobby project or so.

**Update 2**
It seems this is true. Recently Meta added new requirement for facebook apps. Than only "verified" apps can use facebook api, including "Login with Facebook".
And "verification" requires you are registered business in your country. You have to provide documents. So, no facebook API for any hobby apps anymore. :(

Comment: How many apps is your account already a developer or admin on? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app#before-you-start says that 15 is the limit you can have _without_ connection to a meta verified business.

Comment: I have less. I have 7 apps. 4 are not active and i do not use them, some old apps. 3 are planned to be active. They recently deactivated my the only app , another two i planned to activate. So, it doesn't look like a limit

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/email says, _"This permission or feature is only available with business verification."_ - so I guess that's simply how it is then.

Comment: Ok. I agree. Also provider basic info has the same note. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/public_profile
But does this mean that every website that has "Login with facebook" button is now registered as bussiness in their country? I can not believe this. Maybe there is some alternative way to do login? 
I still have no idea why only business can integrate facebook to their websites

Comment: For `public_profile`, it lists the same restriction. And that is the minimum you'd need to even get a user ID, so that you had something you could identify the account by in your system. _"I still have no idea why only business can integrate facebook to their websites"_ - they are trying to crack down on abuse and privacy violations, and this requirement is probably part of that.

Comment: I do not want to believe in this. 
Is this problem for anyone? I can not find messages in web about this is massive problem. I was sure millions of websites use this feature . And only small part of them are business

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2023/02/01/developer-platform-requiring-business-verification-for-advanced-access/ also says, _"Starting July 1, 2023, existing developers will receive a dev alert notifying them when their app becomes eligible to go through the business verification process"_ - so this might not have happened yet for all apps, some might still be flying "under the radar" for now.

Comment: I do not get why `public_profile` is required, because I do not need information from there, just user ID, and user IDs are scoped per app anyway, so there is no information leakage. I use Facebook login only confirm authentication.